# SyncCredentials Don't exist in Realm Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

Im trying to connect my app to a Realm Object Server. The documentation says, to do this you use the below:

```
// create a configuration object
let realmUrl = URL(string: "realms://example.com:9000/~/settings")!
let realmUser = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: username,     password: password)
let config = Realm.Configuration(user: realmUser, realmURL: realmUrl)

// open the Realm with the configuration object
let settingsRealm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

However for SyncCredentials.usernamePassword, XCode says SyncCredentials doesn't exist. From the looks you need to set SyncConfiguration on in Realm.configuration (or the only file I can find RealmConfiguration.swift)

Now I'm in that file theres no option to use SyncCredentials

My question is, how do I simply connect my app with a Realm Object Database using SyncCredentials (or however you're supposed to do it). Been pulling my hair out all day over this, surely it can't be that hard :-(

Answer (score 1):

There seem some mistakes.

`SyncCredentials` is auth info that is used to log in. It is not user object. `Realm.Configuration` doesn't receive `user` and `realmURL` parameters in the initializer. You need to use `SyncConfiguration` instead.

The example code for logging in or instantiating Realm with existing user is the following.

```
let syncServerURL = URL(string: "realm://example.com:9080/~/settings")!
let syncAuthURL = URL(string: "http://example.com:9080")!

if let user = SyncUser.current {
    let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: syncServerURL))
    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
    ...

} else {
    let username = ...
    let password = ...

    let credentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: username, password: password)
    SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: syncAuthURL) { user, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let user = user {
                let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: syncServerURL))
                let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
                ...

            } else {
                // Handle error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please read our documentation again https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#sync

and also our RealmTasks sample project helps you to understand interacting Realm Object Server. https://github.com/realm-demos/realm-tasks

If you still see `SyncCredentials` not found error in above code, probably you didn't setup RealmSwift framework correctly. Please add more info that how did you set up Realm.

Answer (score 1):

Swift Package Manager doesn't load SyncCredentials or SyncUser properly.

I was using the SPM to install RealmSwift as a dependency from IceCream. I removed Realm and IceCream from SPM. Then installed using Carthage to solve the issue.